# Setting rectangle colour in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a custom diagram drawing function, I need a way to set colours of rectangles. This some of the code:

```
# draw many rectangles
for label in labels:
    # derive coords...
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle((x1, y1), width, height)
    rects.append(rect)

collection = PatchCollection(rects, alpha=0.3)
ax.add_collection(collection)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

I'd like to set a colour for the rectangles that is derived from the label. If I call this function again (and the order of labels changes), the same colour should be assigned to the rectangle. I don't care about the colour palette (some distinguishable colours are sufficient for each label). How do I go about this?

**Update**

The possible labels are unknown, so I can't hardcode a colour map. I would need something like a hash function that creates a colour (the hash value) based on the label as an input.

Comment: what does "label->color" mean?  Map label to color, or do you want to map color to label?  If you want to map color to label, just use your color tuple as the label, right?

Comment: I'd like to map a label to a colour, but I don't exactly know which labels to expect (I can't predefine keys for the colour map).

Comment: @orange can you add keys as you add labels?

Comment: If so you could possibly get new colors from one of the predefined colormaps as you find that you have new labels

Comment: @Ajean Yes, that'll be a possible solution...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do it with a dictionary and `map`.

```
colordict = {'l1':'red', 'l2':'green', 'l3':'magenta'}

# Then, where you do plotting:
labels = ['l2', 'l1', 'l3']
colorlist = map(colordict.get, labels)
```

This yields a colorlist that will match your loop

```
['green', 'red', 'magenta']
```

Then, no matter what the order is, the same label will end up with the same color.  It's up to you to define what goes with what ahead of time.